# Unable to access the internet from my VirtualBox CentOS VM via wireless connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, bridge

I have a VirtualBox CentOS VM setup on my Windows 7 machine. I can ping my router, however I am unable to access the outside world.

In Windows I have three network connections setup:

1. Wireless Network Connection (my WWW connection)
2. VirtualBox Host-Only Network (my VM)
3. Local Area Connection (unused)

I have my VM setup to use a bridged adapter to connect through the "Dell Wireless adapter".

Is there any reason why I should be unable to access the outside world from the VM?

I am trying to ping Google with:

> ping 8.8.8.8

and getting connect: network is unreachable

This is a dump from ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:F2:EF:F7  
          inet addr:192.168.0.25  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3310 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:292875 (286.0 KiB)  TX bytes:40593 (39.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20076 (19.6 KiB)  TX bytes:20076 (19.6 KiB)
```

Here is a dump from route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you visit your router page from the VM?

Comment: There's no GUI installed, however if do a wget on the URL then i get a 401 unauthorized (as expected). I can ping the router successfully. Where do you think the issue is? With my router?

Comment: Not necessarily your router. Can you check whether the gateway is probably set on the VM guest, with `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` depending on operating system. Because I guess it can reach the first hop but doesn't know where to sent packets to that have to travel more than a single hop (that thus are not in the network segment).

Comment: I've just updated the main question with a dump from ifconfig on my VM. Does that look like it is configured correctly? How can I tell if the gateway is correctly configured?

Comment: Oh right, that's different on Linux. You can see the routing information with `route -n`, this would also show the gateway if it's configured properly.

Comment: The gateway is showing as 0.0.0.0 as you can see from the dump in the original question. Does this indicate there is an issue with the gateway?

Comment: Posted an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your routing table is incomplete.

Your computer only knows how to route to IPs that start with `192.168` and `169.254` but does not know how to route to any other IPs, we'll want any other IPs to be routed through your router.

If your router would be `192.168.1.1`, you can for example execute:

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.1
```

This would cause the table to look like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

For more information on how this works, execute `man route`.

Comment: OK, I have added my router's IP address (192.168.0.1) to the routing table and I can ping Google on the 8.8.8.8 IP. However, for some reason, I still cannot wget or access any domain (which is a big issue)? Does this mean it is a DNS problem?

Comment: Yes, it sound to me that you haven't followed any guide to set your internet up. [Configure your DNS](http://www.techiecorner.com/123/how-to-add-primary-and-secondary-dns-server-etcresolveconf-linux/).

Comment: Thanks, DNS was infact the problem. I added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as primary and secondary DNS servers respectively using the "setup" command in CentOS. This adds the records to your /etc/resolv.conf file. Thanks for your help!